# Hibernate and Eclipse error

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, tomcat

I'm creating a simple web application with a register form, and I have used Hibernate. But i have this kind of error:

this is the code:
**AddUser.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry;
import javax.security.auth.login.Configuration;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;


@WebServlet("/CreateUser.do")
public class AddUser extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public AddUser() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        ServiceRegistry servReg = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(servReg);

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User u = new User(request.getParameter("firstname"), request.getParameter("lastname"), request.getParameter("login"), request.getParameter("password"));
        session.save(u);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("useradd.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

This is the error: [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y70VZ.png)
How can I do to solve this problem? Thanks you!

@LuisMuñoz

I add also the error if someone want to see it directly.

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Servlet execution threw an exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Cannot instantiate the type Configuration
    The method configure() is undefined for the type Configuration
    The method getProperties() is undefined for the type Configuration
    The method buildSessionFactory(ServiceRegistry) is undefined for the type Configuration

    AddUser.doPost(AddUser.java:32)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

My Eclipse Page:
[ECLIPSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMCv4.png)

Comment: I can't resolve...

Comment: It's better to post plain text instead of images whenever possible. It's a compilation error! Kind of basic java problem.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I add the error directly! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Have you checked the hibernate libs in classpath and its dependencies as well ?

Comment: @MariaSekar Thanks for the answer. Did you say the lib in Eclipse?

Comment: Maybe I haven't import the library for the configuration, but I don't know how I can do

Comment: Place your dependencies within web-inf/lib folder.

Comment: I place the image at the last of the post about Eclipse window. I now put hibernate.cfg.xml file into Java Resource/src

Answer (score -1):

From the error it looks like there is no method configure for Configuration object. Check the javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?javax/security/auth/login/Configuration.html

Comment: This error is related to hibernate configuration not this one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that I Have not install the configuration, but I don't understand how I can do. I read that I should use public static Configuration getConfiguration​(), but I don't understand where to put it.